# Microsoft BotFramework Python bot deployment

Tags: python, azure, botframework, chatbot

I have made an bot using the bot framework. It works well on the emulator.

When I went to deploy it on Azure, I got this:

[image]

There is no option available on the portal.

I need the python specific steps to deploy the bot on Azure.

Comment: You cannot create python bot from portal. You have published it [from cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#4-create-the-bot-application-service) or your [IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#prepare-for-deployment) or from [manual deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#52-zip-up-the-code-directory-manually)

Comment: [Continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-build-continuous-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#continuous-deployment-using-github)

Comment: I tried everything, it I am not sure which step went wrong but the bot is not working after deployment, though it works in emulator

Comment: So what's your problem now?

Comment: I want to publish the chatbot. I am not able to deploy it

Comment: Try from CLI that would be convenient for python.

Answer (score 0):

As Md Farid Uddin Kiron stated in the comments, deploying via CLI is the only way to deploy a python bot. There is no official roadmap to adding Python templating via Azure's 'Create a Resource'.

For the deployment, deploying a python bot via CLI is no different then deploying any other bot via CLI.

1) login (`az login`) and set subscription (`az account set`)

2) create your app registration (`az ad app create`)

3) create the bot application service -- choose only **ONE** of the following:

- a) new resource group (`az deployment create`)
- b) existing resource group with new app service (`az group deployment create --template-file "<path-to-template-with-preexisting-rg.json>" existingAppServicePlan="<name-of-app-service-plan>"`)
- c) existing resource group with existing app service (`az group deployment create --template-file "<path-to-template-with-preexisting-rg.json>" newAppServicePlanName="<name-of-app-service-plan>"`)

4) Zip the code

5) From the directory holding the zip, run the webapp deploy (`az webapp deployment`)

***Two things to note:***

- Those are not the full commands. The commands are dependent on your own deployment. Go to [Deploy Your Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to see the full commands.
- Do not deploy a python bot to any Resource group that contains Windows-based resources, including LUIS resources. Python bots require containerization to run on Azure, and this will conflict with the other resources.